# Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a Mono

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, xsp

I'm trying to send a message in Mono througth my application using the port 587 with the SSL, smtp.gmail.com and get:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Message could not be sent. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid
>   certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a

The most interesting is that that week everything worked and the messages were sent. Now I get a mistake.
Also I tryed  `mozroots --import` but it doesnt help. Also I updated certificate GoogleInternetAuthorityG2.crt but and this doesnt help.

Ubuntu 16.04 with Mono 4.6.2 (Stable 4.6.2.7/08fd525)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mono 4.8](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/) or higher brings a [new TLS stack](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/#tls-12-support) that supports many more encryption algorithms, please upgrade.

Comment: I am unsing 4.6.2 (Stable 4.6.2.7/08fd525)

Comment: then again, please upgrade

Answer (score 3):

Try this before sending the message (It is kind of a hack, but on Mono this is the only thing that worked for me..)

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
             X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    { return true; };
```

Comment: this is an important security risk, please avoid this if you can

Comment: Needed this to get past a Google Sign-in hurdle, though I'm setting it right back to it's previous value after I'm done in case it exposes too many risks.

Comment: The error message states "the authentication or decryption has failed". This workaround applies to the former (authentication failure), but not the latter (decryption failure). YMMV.